# Debugging facebook authentication using Spring Security / Social

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I'm using Spring Security (4.0.1) and Spring Social (1.1.2) to implement authentication to a Spring MVC application using either a Form of using an existing facebook account. Form authentication is working perfectly. However, facebook authentication is not working.

As far as I can see, I've setup the pieces needed to make this work:

- created a class that implements SocialConfigurer, adding the facebook connection factory, useridsource (existing AuthenticationNameUserIdSource) and usersconnectionrepository (custom made for use with OrientDB)
- Added a line to apply SpringSocialConfigurer in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
- Added a SocialUserDetailsService bean

This seems to be working for the most part, but the authentication is not completed. When calling /auth/facebook, the following happens:

- redirect to facebook.com oauth (login mechanism)
- callback to /auth/facebook on my application, with a lengthy code variable and state variable
- redirect to my defaultFailureUrl, without warning, error or any message in log or request variables

So there is something going wrong, but I can't determine what or where exactly.
I've tried to set logging for org.springframework.social to FINEST, but that doesn't show any messages.

Does anyone have any tips how to determine the cause of this failure to complete authentication using facebook?

Thanks in advance,

Sem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, I had to configure log4j correctly in order to receive all of Spring's log messages in my default server log.
These log messages helped me to determine the issue at hand: my app signature had been changed. Quite an awkward issue to be stuck with for a long time ..

Hope this helps someone else struggling with Spring issues, make sure you have log4j included in your project, create a log4j properties file and make sure it is available to your container.

For me the following configuration worked:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

I put it in the domain config for my glassfish domain, and added it to the JVM options using the Dlog4j.configuration property.

Regards,

Sem

Comment: We also had a problem two days ago with Facebook OAuth: https://lingohub.com/blog/2015/12/workaround-for-broken-facebook-oauth-using-spring-social/

Comment: what do u mean by "my app signature had been changed"?